# Control the flow of method execution

Tags: java

I have a super abstract class consisted of couple of methods. Those methods should be executed in order. I want to let the methods to be overridden, but not to change the order of method execution. Also, the return type of each method is required to analyzed in order to execute the next method. The type of return value of each method can be varied. Therefore fore said return object's analyzing should be allowed to do in the child classes.

```
public abstract class TaskManageer {

    public abstract <A> A init();

    public abstract <B> B start();

    public abstract <C> C shutDown();

    public final boolean  runManager(){

       init();
       start();
       shutDown();

    }
}
```

The method runManager() has been made as 'final', so that child classes cannot change the order . But, the out put of init() method is required to analyze before the start() method. Also, output of start() method is required to begin shutDown() method.

This analysis should be allowed for the child classes.

Anyone let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Parameter would be my advice as well. The start() method signature would look like this: public abstract <B> B start( A initializationResult );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your analysis should build on the type returned by your methods you will need to define the type on your class.

```
public abstract class TaskManager<A, B, C> {

    public abstract A init();

    public abstract B start();

    public abstract C shutDown();

    public abstract void analyzeAfterInit(A initResult);

    public abstract void analyzeAfterStart(B startResult);

    public final booelan  runManager(){

       A initResult = init();
       analyzeAfterInit(initResult);
       B startResult = start();
       analyzeAfterStart(startResult);
       shutDown();

    }
}
```

*Addition: 
If you have got specific requirements to the types of your generic paramters you can use [bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) such as `TaskManager<A, B, C extends Number>`

A possible subclass might look as follows:

```
public class MyTaskManager extends TaskManager<String, Process, Integer> {

    // private fields ....

    public String init() {
        return "echo 'Hello'";
    }

    public Process start() {
        Process p = new Process(this.command);
        p.start();
        return p;
    }

    public Integer shutDown() {
        int exitCode = this.process.stop();
        return exitCode;
    }

    public void analyzeAfterInit(String initResult) {
        this.command = initResult;
        verifyCommand(initResult);
    }

    public void analyzeAfterStart(Process startResult) {
        this.process = startResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . This is helpful. but can you be more clear with the generic types since  A, B , C can be any type of objects. Take a look at my question.

Comment: Well, you can define `A`, `B` and `C` per subclass. They can be defined as any type you want. If the same subclass can return different types you should introduce a common interface for your results that provides the methods you need for your analysis. Worst case, you could just use `Object` but that would diminish the gain of the generic types

Answer (score 2):

I would pass the results of previous methods as a parameter. The next method can then work with it.

Since you want to ensure the proper order of methods, also make sure that the inherited methods cannot be called from outside, therefore change the visibiilty to `protected` instead of `public`.

```
public abstract class TaskManageer <A, B, C> {

    protected abstract A init();

    protected abstract B start(A a);

    protected abstract C shutDown(B b);

    public final boolean runManager(){
       A a = init();
       B b = start(a);
       C c = shutDown(b);
       return c.getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . This is helpful. but can you be more clear with the generic types since  A, B , C can be any type of objects. Take a look at my question.